# PostgreSQL create temp table from query

Tags: sql, postgresql

When I using query to select values to temp table like this:

```
drop table if exists tTemp;

select  tt.id, tt.name
into    tTemp
from    test.TestTable tt
```

It's work great. But when I using this construction in function I have this error:

> [42601] ERROR: "tTemp" is not a known variableq

Why this construction don't work in function?

Comment: `into` has a different meaning in PL/pgSQL code. See  the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW)

Answer (score 1):

Use the standard compliant CRATE TABLE AS SELECT instead of the discouraged select ... into to avoid the ambiguity between storing the result of a query into a PL/pgSQL variable and creating a new table:

```
drop table if exists tTemp;

create table ttemp 
as
select  tt.id, tt.name
from    test.TestTable tt
```

This is one of the reasons [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtableas.html) recommends to use CREATE TABLE AS instead of select into

Answer (score 0):

its may be work :

```
INSERT INTO tTemp
select  tt.id, tt.name
from    test.TestTable tt
```